# apex test class to cover the method CompareTo :

Tags: apex

i have below code in my apex class

```
global class Payment implements Comparable{
    public string id;
    public string YearQ;
    public string YearMo;
    public Date asOf;
    public decimal payment = 0;
    public decimal revenue = 0;
    public decimal attritionRate = 0;//DE420
    public decimal payOnRevenue = 0;//DE 420

    //only used by branch group sort (compareTo) to provide 0 values for missing payments
    public Payment() {
    }

    public Payment(PODA_Exhibit_Payment__c pmt) {
        this.id = pmt.id;
        this.YearQ = pmt.PODA_Contracted_Agency_Payment__r.YearQrt__c;
        this.YearMo = PODA_Util.getYearMoFromYearQ(this.YearQ);
        this.payment = pmt.Total_Payment__c;
        this.revenue = pmt.Total_Flown_Revenue__c;
        // DE 420 - Gain Calculator 9/9/14
        this.attritionRate = pmt.Attrition_Rate__c;
        this.payOnRevenue = pmt.Pay_On_Revenue__c;
    }

    public Payment(PODA_Branch_Payment_Summary__c pmt) {
        this.id = pmt.id;
        this.YearQ = pmt.YearQrt__c;
        this.YearMo = PODA_Util.getYearMoFromYearQ(this.YearQ);
        this.payment = pmt.Total_Payment__c;
        this.revenue = pmt.Total_Flown_Revenue__c;
    }

    public Payment(PODA_Branch_Exhibit_Payment__c pmt) {
        this.id = pmt.id;
        this.YearQ = pmt.YearQrt__c;
        this.YearMo = PODA_Util.getYearMoFromYearQ(this.YearQ);
        this.payment = pmt.Total_Payment__c;
        this.revenue = pmt.Total_Flown_Revenue__c;
    }

    public void addPayment(PODA_Branch_Payment_Summary__c pmt) {
      this.payment += pmt.Total_Payment__c;
      this.revenue += pmt.Total_Flown_Revenue__c;
    }

    public void addPayment(PODA_Branch_Exhibit_Payment__c pmt) {
        this.payment += pmt.Total_Payment__c;
        this.revenue += pmt.Total_Flown_Revenue__c;
    }

    public void addPayment(PODA_Exhibit_Payment__c pmt) {
        this.payment += pmt.Total_Payment__c;
        this.revenue += pmt.Total_Flown_Revenue__c;
        this.payOnRevenue += pmt.Pay_On_Revenue__c;
    }

    public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
        Payment compareToHP = (Payment)compareTo;
        return this.YearQ.compareTo(compareToHP.YearQ);
    }

}
```

///  Payments is the inner class in the main apex class and i want to write test class for this.

I am facing issue while writing test for below method in the above code

```
 public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
        Payment compareToHP = (Payment)compareTo;
        return this.YearQ.compareTo(compareToHP.YearQ);
    }
```

// i have created a class with name as Object1 in the test class and try to call the main class method as below

```
 PODA_Data.Payment objPODA = new PODA_Data.Payment();
 object1 obj = new object1();
  integer i = objPODA.compareTo(obj);
```

Facing error as below :

> Error Message System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime
>   type PODA_Data_Test.object1 to PODA_Data.Payment

// could you please help me how to write test class for the above method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a test method (or multiple methods) for the `compareTo` of this form:

```
@IsTest
static void compareTo() {

    PODA_Data.Payment p1 = new PODA_Data.Payment(new PODA_Branch_Payment_Summary__c(YearQrt__c = '1'));
    PODA_Data.Payment p2 = new PODA_Data.Payment(new PODA_Branch_Payment_Summary__c(YearQrt__c = '2'));

    PODA_Data.Payment p3 = new PODA_Data.Payment(new PODA_Branch_Exhibit_Payment__c(YearQrt__c = '3'));
    PODA_Data.Payment p4 = new PODA_Data.Payment(new PODA_Branch_Exhibit_Payment__c(YearQrt__c = '4'));

    PODA_Data.Payment p5 = new PODA_Data.Payment();

    // TODO Also create PODA_Exhibit_Payment__c ones; bit more awkward

    System.assert(p2.compareTo(p1) > 0);
    System.assert(p1.compareTo(p2) < 0);
    System.assert(p1.compareTo(p1) == 0);

    System.assert(p4.compareTo(p3) > 0);
    System.assert(p3.compareTo(p4) < 0);
    System.assert(p3.compareTo(p3) == 0);

    System.assert(p3.compareTo(p1) > 0);
    System.assert(p1.compareTo(p3) < 0);

    // Method compareTo will NPE with this so test will highlight missing guard code
    System.assert(p5.compareTo(p1) < 0);

    ...
}
```

The point of tests is to make sure that code works so always include asserts for the required behaviour and cover a reasonable number of permutations.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're not creating a Setup data for Payment properly. Instead of passing `obj` as `Object` type, pass `payment` as `Payment` type. Because by default every custom object inherits `Object` class. Rest of the code seems to be fine.

Up casting is handled by compiler itself but for down casting it will throw an error. Try below example:

```
static testMethod void  testCompareTo() {
    test.startTest();
    PODA_Data.Payment objPODA = new PODA_Data.Payment();
    Payment payment = new Payment();
    integer i = objPODA.compareTo(payment);
    test.stopTest();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, i have tried the above but didn't worked